# Migration from maven to gradle

Tags: java, maven, apache-flex, mxml, gradlefx

We are migrating maven project to gradle. We have flex for front end and as requested we are migrating it as well using gradlefx. Have added the dependencies:

```
dependencies{
    classpath 'com.adobe.flex.framework:flex-framework:4.0.0.14159'
    classpath files("./libs/flex/parsley-core-3.0.0.swc")
    classpath files("./libs/flex/parsley-flex-3.0.0.swc")
    classpath files("./libs/flex/legacy-parsley-commands-2.5.0.swc")
    classpath files("./libs/flex/spicelib-commands-3.1.1.swc")
    classpath files("./libs/flex/spicelib-reflect-3.0.0.swc")
    classpath files("./libs/flex/spicelib-util-3.1.0.swc")
}
```

2.My mxml has contents like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Object xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns="http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley">
<fx:Script><![CDATA[//some imports]]></fx:Script></Object>
```

However on build am getting following error.

> [ant:java] Java Result: 1
>   FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task `:Common_Components:compileFlex`.

  > java.lang.Exception: mxmlc execution failed: Loading configurationfile D:\Softwares\flex_sdk_4.6\frameworks\flex-config.xmlD:\Xyz\Workspace\Common_Components\src\com\abc\common\MenuContext.mxml(9): Error: Could not resolve  to a component implementation. xmlns:presentation1="com.abc.helpframework.presentation.*">`

The same setup is working for other mxml file. I doubt with object tag, not very sure though.